# Handling UTC Conversions in MERN Application

Tags: node.js, mern

I'm creating a MERN booking application.

[Availability in Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2DOu.png)

The appointments table is intentionally empty for now.

My endpoint for fetching available times:

```
// get available slots
app.get('/available-times', (req, res) => {
  const { date } = req.query;
  if (!date) {
    return res.status(400).send('Date query parameter is required');
  }

  const inputDate = new Date(date);
  const dayOfWeek = inputDate.getDay();

  const sqlAvailabilities = 'SELECT * FROM availability WHERE weekday = ?';

  db.query(sqlAvailabilities, [dayOfWeek], (err, availabilityResults) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }

    const sqlAppointments = 'SELECT * FROM appointments WHERE date = ?';
    db.query(sqlAppointments, [date], (err, appointmentResults) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
      }

      // Create one-hour increments from availability spans
      const oneHourIncrements = availabilityResults.flatMap(avail => {
        const increments = [];
        const startTime = new Date(`1970-01-01T${avail.start_time}`);
        const endTime = new Date(`1970-01-01T${avail.end_time}`);

        while(startTime < endTime) {
          const endIncrement = new Date(startTime.getTime());
          endIncrement.setHours(endIncrement.getHours() + 1);

          increments.push({
            start: startTime.toISOString().split('T')[1].substring(0, 5),
            end: endIncrement.toISOString().split('T')[1].substring(0, 5),
          });

          // Move to next hour
          startTime.setHours(startTime.getHours() + 1);
        }

        return increments;
      });

      // Filter out booked slots
      const availableTimes = oneHourIncrements.filter(increment => {
        return !appointmentResults.some(app => {
          const appStart = `1970-01-01T${app.start_time}`;
          const appEnd = `1970-01-01T${app.end_time}`;
          const incStart = `1970-01-01T${increment.start}`;
          const incEnd = `1970-01-01T${increment.end}`;
          return (incStart < appEnd) && (incEnd > appStart);
        });
      });

      console.log('Received date:', date);
      console.log('Calculated dayOfWeek:', dayOfWeek);
      console.log('Availability results:', availabilityResults);
      console.log('Appointment results:', appointmentResults);
      console.log('One-hour increments:', oneHourIncrements);
      console.log('Available Times:', availableTimes);
      res.json(availableTimes);
    });
  });
});
```

And the terminal outputs when I access `http://localhost:5000/available-times?date=2024-03-03`:

> Received date: 2024-03-03
>
> Calculated dayOfWeek: 6
>
> Availability results: []
>
> Appointment results: []
>
> One-hour increments: []
>
> Available Times: []

I expect the calculated dayOfWeek to be 0 for Sunday, and the resulting output to include the available time slot from my database.

I'm lost on where the conversion from 0 to 6 is happening.

Googling extensively, chatgpt, etc.

Comment: Because you're typing `2023-03-04`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean...